# Should the datatype of lookup fields in Access be different from the source table?

Tags: vba, ms-access, types, lookup-tables

I am trying to use VBA to populate a bunch of tables based on the values of fields in a main table. The main table has a field "Sample Name" which is linked to a lookup field in each of the tables I am trying to populate. In the main table the data type of Sample Name is dbText (10), however I'm noticing the data type of the lookup field based on Sample Name is dbLong (4). This causes problems for my code as I am trying to add new records to each table, and when I try to set the value of the lookup field to a corresponding value from Sample Name (stored in a string) I receive a data type conversion error.

Is there a reason the lookup field has a different data type than its source table? Is the lookup field storing some sort of index like the key from the main table and simply displaying the corresponding value from Sample Name?

Additional background:

The block of code (within a Case statement) that throws the error is as follows, at this point revlitho has been defined as a recordset, the "Sample Name" field is the lookup field in question, and sampName is the string variable storing the corresponding Sample Name from the main table. It is also worth noting that at time of error revlitho.fields("Sample Name").value returns Null, I am unsure if this is the default for empty fields in a recordset:

```
Case "Standard Image Reverse Lithography"
        revlitho.AddNew
        revlitho.Fields("Sample Name").Value = sampName
        revlitho.Update
```

Comment: Because the lookup field expects you to save the ID of record from lookup table, not the descriptive text. I advise not to build lookup fields in table because of this confusion. Build comboboxes on form. What is the combobox RowSource sql? Advise not to use spaces in naming convention.

Comment: _Is the lookup field storing some sort of index_. Exactly. So, either get rid of the lookup field which will cause nothing but trouble, or use a query that includes the table used in the lookup field.